# Get default value (and context column) when group by returns no records in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a query that I need for it to return a record even when there are no records. In the case where there are records, I simply want those records returned. On the other hand, when there are no records, I need it to still return a record but with the value for the "context" column (the `GROUP BY` column) equal to the value of the `GROUP BY` column that did not meet the criteria and a default value for aggregate function/column (e.g., `0`). I tried a subquery:

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT
      CONTEXT,
      SUM(VAL)
    FROM
      A_TABLE
    WHERE
      COL = 'absent'
    GROUP BY
      CONTEXT
  )
FROM
  DUAL;
```

but anything greater than one column in the subquery `SELECT` clause fails w/ a "too many values" message.

I also tried a UNION (with a little more context to more faithfully represent my situation):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      CONTEXT,
      SUM(VAL)
    FROM
      A_TABLE
    WHERE
      COL = 'absent'
    GROUP BY
      CONTEXT
    UNION
    SELECT
      CONTEXT,
      0
    FROM
      B_TABLE
  )
  AB_TABLE
INNER JOIN C_TABLE C -- just a table that I need to join to
ON
  C.ID = AB_TABLE.C_ID
WHERE
  C.ID     = 10
AND ROWNUM = 1  -- excludes 2nd UNION subquery result when 1st returns record;
```

This one does work but I don't know why since the 2nd UNION subquery does not seem to be expressly connected w/ the first (I need the 2nd CONTEXT value to be the same as the 1st for the case where the 1st returns no records). The problem is that the real query does not return any records when I try to implement a similar strategy. I would like to see if there's a better way to approach this problem and perhaps get it to work for the real query (not included as it is too large and somewhat sensitive).

Comment: You are explaining your code. That doesn't help us help you. Please describe the problem, in plain English: what are the inputs (what tables, what columns, what data types - only those columns relevant for your problem; what is the desired output, and according to what logic the output derives from the input). Perhaps we can guess at those from the code you wrote - but that kind of reverse engineering is time consuming and often our guesses are wrong - especially when the code does NOT do what you need it to do.

Comment: @mathguy I gave the question a more thorough treatment as a result of your comment. Please let me know if it is still not satisfactory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question, but let's try.

I believe what you are saying is this. You have a table called `A_TABLE`, with columns `CONTEXT, VAL, COL` (and perhaps others as well).

You want to group by `CONTEXT`, and get the sum of `VAL` but only for those rows where `COL = 'absent'`. Otherwise you want to return a default value (let's say 0).

This can be done with conditional aggregation. The condition is in a `CASE` expression within the `SUM`, not in a `WHERE` clause (as you saw already, if you filter by `COL='absent'`, in a `WHERE` clause, the query - past the `WHERE` clause - has no knowledge of the `CONTEXT` values that don't appear in any rows with `COL = 'absent'`).

If the "default value" was `NULL`, you could do it like this:

```
select   context, sum(case when col = 'absent' then value end) as val
from     a_table
group by context
;
```

If the default value is anything other than `NULL`, the temptation may be to use `NVL()` around the sum. However, if `VAL` may be `NULL`, then it is possible that `SUM(VAL)` is `NULL` even when there are rows with `COL = 'absent'`. To address that possibility, you must leave the sum as `NULL`  in those cases, and instead set the value to 0 (or whatever other "default value") only when there are NO rows with `COL = 'absent'`. Here is one way to do that. Still a standard "conditional" aggregate query:

```
select   context,
         case when count(case when col = 'absent' then 1 end) > 0
              then sum(case when col = 'absent' then value end)
              else 0                 --  or whatever "default value" you must assign here
         end  as val
from     a_table
group by context
;
```

Comment: I appreciate you persevering w/ the state of the OP and giving such a well thought-out and explained answer. This is exactly what I was hoping to find -- a meta-where filter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could handle it that avoids the two additional tables (B_TABLE and C_TABLE).

```
SELECT context
  , MAX(val)
FROM (
  SELECT context
     , SUM(val) as val
  FROM a_table
  WHERE col = 'absent'
  GROUP BY context
 UNION
  SELECT context
     , 0 as val
  FROM a_table
) t
GROUP BY context
```

This assumes the default value you want to return is 0 and that any value in A_TABLE.VAL will be a positive integer.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c6ca0/20

Comment: hmmm, looks like it may work out for me. I do have 2 aggregates in my real problem and they are both highly correlated. I am sure I can get away with `MAX(VAL), MAX(VAL2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.context
     , sum(a.val)
  FROM b_table b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN a_table a
      ON    a.context = b.context
        AND a.col = 'absent'
  GROUP BY b.context
```